# Cannot convert mp4 to gif using gifify

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, gif

I am getting the following error when trying to convert an `mp4` video to `gif` using `gifify`

```
Unable to find application named 'Cloud'
```

Does anyone know how to debug or investigate this type of issue?

[image: error]

Comment: `brew reinstall gifify` works here is that the command you're using that's failing?

Comment: Reinstall command works and finishes without errors. But error occurs when typing gifify command.

Comment: what's your `pwd`? do you have this file installed [it calls it anyway] `/usr/local/bin/convert`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that gifify "by default" attempts to upload the gif to "CloudApp" ("Cloud" in earlier versions) https://github.com/jclem/gifify/blob/master/gifify.sh#L88

So run it like `gifify -n movie.mp4` instead.

I suggest you add a new issue telling them to log better when there is no CloudApp installed here: https://github.com/jclem/gifify/issues